# Chaining find() to val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chaining

Is there a way to chain `find()` following `val()`?

For example, given the following code, I would like to clear the values of all the inputs but only toggle the `required` property of the inputs that have a class of `.required`:

```
$('#some-selector')
    .find(':input')
    .val('')
    .find('.required')
    .prop('required', someBoolean);
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/), it is apparent that `val()` returns a string, number or array. Seems to me that `find()` will not function on this return value as I believe it needs a jQuery object.

So a few questions:

1. Where is my gap in jQuery understanding such that I attempted to chain `find()` to `val()`
2. How would I accomplish my requirement: I want to clear all inputs and toggle required on those with class `.required`.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your logic is flawed anyway, inputs can't have any children so you cannot do a `.find` on them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not with the chaining, but your repeated use of `find()`.

The first `find()` retrieves all `:input` elements and clears their value, which is fine. However the second `find()` is then searching *inside* all those `input` elements for `.required`. This cannot be valid as `input` cannot have child elements (except `select`, but that's not applicable in this case).

You instead need to search within the *current* collection for elements with the class of `required`. To do that use `filter()` instead:

```
$('#some-selector')
  .find(':input').val('')
  .filter('.required').prop('required', someBoolean);
```